# Setting an array created in a for loop to a string which is part of a list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, python-3.x

I have created a for loop where the final result in the loop is an array called dataNew as seen below:

```
flatID = [flat1, flat2, flat3, flat4, flat5, flat6, flat7, flat8, flat9,  flat10, flat11, flat12, flat13, flat14, flat15]

oscimg = ["none"]*15

for i in range(0,14):
  fakeBias = flatID[i]
  #Biascorrection?
  fakeData = np.zeros((636.,2400 ), dtype = "float")
  fakeData.shape
  biasPerRow=np.median(fakeBias[:,598:636],axis=1)
  biasPerRow.shape

  dataNew=fakeData[0:598,:]
  dataNew.shape

  for i in range(635):
    dataNew[ : , i ] -= biasPerRow[ i ]
  oscimg[i] = dataNew
```

I am working with various fits files where each of the data in the fits file is set to a element in the flatID list.

Where my issue lies is in setting the dataNew array to a string or a list element where that for each iteration of the loop, I can set the final values of dataNew array to either a string which changes with every iteration such that the final result will be 15 different variations of dataNew arrays being set to strings which I can use. However I am wrong in the sense of using oscimg[i] to set the string element as I return the following error.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/*****/Python/Assignment/Ag3.py in <module>()
    110   for i in range(635):
    111     dataNew[ : , i ] -= biasPerRow[ i ]
--> 112   oscimg[i] = dataNew
    113 
    114 # Example 11.3: Read in dark frames, bias subtract and createmaster darks

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(0,14):
  #...
  for i in range(635):
    dataNew[ : , i ] -= biasPerRow[ i ]
  oscimg[i] = dataNew
```

You are using `i` as the variable for both of your `for` loops. The second one will override the value of the first, so the last line will evaluate as `oscimg[634] = dataNew`.

Use different names for your loops.

```
for i in range(0,14):
  #...
  for j in range(635):
```